# $f(Y|X=x) \sim B(n,\frac{1}{2})$ is function of $x$ its pmf is ${{n} \choose {x}}(\frac{1}{2})^{x}(\frac{1}{2})^{n-x} $?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

> Let $X$ be the number of tosses of a fair coin required to get the
> first head. If $Y | X = n$ is distributed as Binomial$(n, \frac{1}{2}
> )$, then what is $P(Y = 1)$?

Before attempting this I have a question in my mind?

**$f(Y|X=x)$ is function of $x$, so I can write its pmf as ${{n} \choose {x}}(\frac{1}{2})^{x}(\frac{1}{2})^{n-x} $ or is it ${{n} \choose {y}}(\frac{1}{2})^{y}(\frac{1}{2})^{n-y} ?$**

Clear this doubt for me please.

Now from question $X$ follows geometric distributions.

$P(X=x)=(\frac{1}{2})^{x-1}(\frac{1}{2})$

$f(Y|X)=\dfrac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)} \implies f(Y|X)\cdot {f_X(x)}=f(x,y)$

Then I have to find marginal of $Y$ and $P(Y=1)$ but I am stuck initially

Comment: $f(Y=y\mid X=x)$ is a function of **both** $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question, that $X=x,\:Y|X=x\sim B(x,0.5)$. For a binomial distribution $B(n,p)$, the pmf is given by $$p(k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$
In this case we have $n=x,\:p=0.5$. So the pmf is $$\mathbb P(Y=y|X=x)=\binom{x}{y}(0.5)^y(1-0.5)^{x-y}=\binom{x}{y}(0.5)^x$$
Using the law of total expectation,
$$\mathbb P(Y=1)=\mathbb E(\mathbb P(Y=1|X))=\mathbb E\left(\binom{X}{1}(0.5)^X\right)\\ =\sum_{k=1}^\infty\binom{k}{1}(0.5)^k\cdot (0.5)^{k-1}(0.5)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(0.5)^{2k}=\frac{4}{9}$$

Comment: So using this $P(Y=1)$ will be $\sum_x \binom{x}{y}(0.5)^y(1-0.5)^{x-y}=\frac{(0.5)}{(1-0.5)}\sum_x\binom{x}{1}(1-0.5)^{x}=\sum_xx(\frac{1}{2})^{x}=\frac{a}{1-r}+\frac{dr}{(1-r)^2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1\cdot \frac{1}{2}}{\frac{9}{4}}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{9}=\frac{9+4}{18}$ I am not getting correct ans could you please check ?

Comment: @Daman edited my answer, you can take a look

Comment: you can't just sum all the conditional probabilities over $x$

Comment: How did $P(Y=1)=E(P(Y=1|X))$ ?

Comment: $\mathbb P(Y=1|X)=\mathbb E(\mathbf 1_{Y=1}|X)$, so $\mathbb E(\mathbb P(Y=1|X))=\mathbb E(\mathbb E(\mathbf 1_{Y=1}|X))=\mathbb E(\mathbf 1_{Y=1})=\mathbb P(Y=1)$